Sigma fp lens recommendations for a smaller, lighter setup
I'm currently using a Sigma fp for both video and stills. My go-to lens has been the Sigma 24-70mm f/2.8 DG DN Art, but I find it a bit bulky and heavy, especially for everyday shooting.
Recently, I've been experimenting with vintage adapted lenses for stills, and I've realized how much I enjoy the smaller form factor.  I'm now considering switching to a prime lens setup and the Sigma 45mm f/2.8 DG DN Contemporary and 90mm f/2.8 DG DN Contemporary lenses have caught my eye.
Would these be a good fit for the Sigma fp, offering good image quality while keeping the setup compact? Or are there other lenses (prime or zoom) that I should consider?

It's not exactly as if you're comparing zoom apples to prime apples, are you? Your zoom has a shorter focal length at the wide angle end. Starting around 24 mm (and wider), you start to see larger front elements, tulip-style lens hoods, etc. But the widest prime you're talking about is 45 mm, which is right in the range of some of the most compact primes.
As far as compactness, that's really more of a personal tradeoff of what you value. The 90 mm you're considering has a little bit more reach than your current zoom's 70 mm, but your zoom obviously is quite a bit wider than the 45 mm you're considering.
If you're really into saving bag weight and space, you could probably shave a bit more by using older SLR lenses with the same mount, and keep the mount adapter on your Sigma fp body. That way, for each additional adapted lens you carry (assuming they're the same original mount, of course), you save the adapter length (or the equivalent adapter length of a L-mount lens).
As far as if the Sigma 45 and 90 mm f/2.8 primes are good... they're absolutely fine. They aren't as spectacular, as far as primes go, as say the 35 mm f/1.2 (or f/1.4) or the 50 mm f/1.2 (or f/1.4) (the nearest lenses to the 45 mm f/2.8), or the 85 mm f/1.4 (comparing the 90 mm f/2.8), obviously. But then again those f/1.2 or f/1.4 lenses are 3× the price of the f/2.8 lenses you're talking about.
